# Trying to show/hide a user control in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to show and hide a usercontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that, just don't new up the item. if the item is on the visual tree there will already be an instance of it, if its not on the visual tree then after you new up make sure to add it to an element in the visual tree.

Comment: +1 Tam is correct - you should not be new()-ing the item, if you need to make a new one then you need to add it to the parent that it is going to be in. Idealy you should be doing this by binding the visibility property to something in a view state.